# Simple system of matrix ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We are given $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}, b\in \mathbb R^{n \times 1}$ where $d > n$ and $rank(A) = n$, and initial values $W_0 \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}, x_0 \in \mathbb R^{d \times 1}$

I'm interested in solving the following system of equations:

$\begin{bmatrix}\dot W = -A^T(AWx-b)x^T\\\dot x = -W^TA^T(AWx-b)\end{bmatrix}$ given $W(0) = W_0, x(0) = x_0$.

I'm completely stumped, it's very difficult that the variables are coupled together. Is there a method for solving this?

Comment: I would use a program like mathematica to solve this system.

Comment: $W^T \dot W -\dot x x^T = 0$

Comment: Continuing from Cesareo's observation, it might be good to first consider a simpler version of the problem, e.g. $w'=wx^2, x'=w^2x$, where both $w$ and $x$ are real valued; it's possible to solve this system explicitly using elementary methods.

Comment: How? I'm guessing I need to define a new variable $r = w^2-x^2$ but even then I'm missing the second transformation, as I need two new variables. Not to mention it doesn't carry over nicely to the matrix case. I realize this is probably very simple, but I've never encountered coupled non linear systems of ODE. As elementary as the methods of solutions are, and Google isn't being very helpful.

Comment: @OriaGruber First we have that $ww'=w^2x^2=x'x$. Integrating w/r/t $t$ we get $w^2=x^2+c_1$, where $c_1$ is an anonymous constant. Plugging this expression into the second equation we get $\dfrac{1}{(x^2+c_1)x}x'=1$, where a case analysis with cases $c_1=0$, $c_1\neq0$ is needed. In each case the denominator on the LHS splits into functions whose antiderivatives are known.

Comment: That's fantastic, but won't work in the matrix case I think. Consider $\int \dot x x^Tdt$. It's a matrix where one of the components is $\int x_1'x_2dt$. We have nothing to do about this besides integration by parts (I think) and that won't lead anywhere useful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\dot W \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}-A^T(AWx-b)x^T\\  -W^TA^T(AWx-b)\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}- ∇_W \tfrac{1}{2}‖AWx-b‖^2_2 \\  - ∇_x \tfrac{1}{2}‖AWx-b‖^2_2\end{bmatrix}
$$

So what we have here is simply the **gradient flow** $(*)$

$$ \boxed{\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \begin{bmatrix}W \\ x\end{bmatrix}= -∇ \tfrac{1}{2}‖AWx-b‖^2_2}$$

Which should either get stuck in a saddle point or converge to a minimizer of $f([\begin{smallmatrix}W\\x\end{smallmatrix}]) = \frac{1}{2}‖AWx-b‖^2_2$, i.e. towards a pair $(W, x)$ satisfying

$$Wx ∈ (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb + \ker(A)$$

Note that the inverse exists as per the rank condition you have given. Obviously there is redundancy here, so the initial condition will determine how the final $(W, x)$ pair looks like.

---

$(*)$ Note that if you apply the forward Euler method one recovers a standard gradient descent scheme.

Comment: Notice that $(A, b)$ is an under-determined system, and as such has infinitely many solutions. Generally we are not gauranteed convergence to the minimal solution $(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$, gradient descent / flow can converge to a "random" solution depending on initialization. Also this is a non convex problem so there's no gaurantee we will converge to a solution at all, but will get stuck at a saddle point. I don't think it's that simple.

Comment: A simple of example of this can be to initialize $Wx$ to be any solution not $(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ which is a stationary point, or the saddle point $W=0, x=0$

Comment: I think the comment I posted in the question, that shows that the real valued method proposed by Alp Uzman won't work in the vector / matrix case, is suggestive that maybe a closed form solution doesn't exist.

Comment: @OriaGruber At the very least, the gradient flow formulation shows that $\tfrac{1}{2}‖AWx-b‖^2_2$ is a decreasing quantity. In particular, the system should be guaranteed to either converge towards some local minimum or get stuck in a saddle point. It could be useful to investigate the geometry of the set of saddle points.